# Is there a difference between decoded picture buffer and coded picture buffer?

Tags: mpeg

When it comes to H.264 video, is there a difference between Decoded Picture Buffer (DBP) and Coded Picture Buffer (CPB), or are they the same thing?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how H.264 encodes frame data? I don't know the answer, just trying to understand.

Comment: No, not how it encodes. But whether they are just 2 ways of saying the same thing or not.

Comment: I'm not familiar with H.264 details, just making sure that you're not asking a general question about encoded vs. decoded frames. Liked compressed vs. decompressed frames. Not sure why you got a down vote, I'm curious myself now. I guess that's just SO for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coded picture buffer is a buffer that contains still compressed video data and is important for rate control of streaming video. The decoded picture buffer contains decoded yuv frames before they are displayed. They are not the same thing.